# How to create an immutable builder of an immutable class that contains a set?

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder

I am trying to create an immutable builder of an immutable class that contains a Set.  It should be an immutable set really but for now I have to use the regular JCF classes.  Using the standard pizza example, I have the pizza base as a mandatory parameter and toppings as optional, 0 or more allowed.  I imagine that each call to `addToppings()` will create a new immutable builder with a set of toppings and then finally when build is called the Pizza object will be delivered.  I just don't know how to build up the immutable set of `toppings`.  Here is my code:

```
public class Pizza {

private Pizza(Base base, Set<Topping> toppings) {
    this.base = base;
    this.toppings = toppings;
}

public static PizzaBuilder createBuilder(Base pizzaBase) {
    return new PizzaBuilder(new Pizza(pizzaBase, null));
}

public static class PizzaBuilder {
    private PizzaBuilder(Pizza pizza) {
        this.pizza = pizza;
    }

    public PizzaBuilder addTopping(Topping topping) {
        return new PizzaBuilder(new Pizza(pizza.base, ???));
    }

    public Pizza build() {
        return pizza;
    }

    final private Pizza pizza;
}

public Collection<Topping> getToppings() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(toppings);
}

enum Base {DEEP_PAN, THIN}
enum Topping {MOZZARELLA, TOMATO, ANCHOVIES, PEPPERONI}

final private Base base;
final private Set<Topping> toppings;
```

}

I know this is a deviation from the 'standard' new builder pattern but I find the storing and copying of values there inelegant because the target class already defines what fields are needed.

Comment: Why must the builder be immutable?

Comment: It doesn't have to be, in fact its real world counterpart isn't.  It's just that I want to know how to do it this way.  It must be possible! But then perhaps all I need here really is a proper immutable set class.

Answer (score 3):

```
public PizzaBuilder addTopping(Topping topping) {
    Set<Topping> toppings = null;
    if (pizza.toppings == null)
        toppings = new LinkedHashSet<Topping>();
    else
        toppings = new LinkedHashSet<Topping>(pizza.toppings);
    toppings.add(topping);
    return new PizzaBuilder(new Pizza(pizza.base, toppings));
}
```

Is that what you're interested in?  I chose LinkedHashSet to maintain the order of the toppings.

Comment: This would work, and I could avoid the null check by passing an empty set to the Pizza constructor the first time (in fact I should do that).  But again, this does a lot of what I think is unnecessary copying.

Comment: If you want it to be immutable I dont think you can avoid copy some stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You could clone the old set, add the new entry, and then use that one. `EnumSet` is more efficient than `Set` by the way:

```
final private EnumSet<Topping> toppings;

public PizzaBuilder addTopping(Topping topping) {
    EnumSet<Topping> newToppings = EnumSet.of(topping);
    if (toppings != null) {
        newToppings.addAll(toppings);
    }
    return new PizzaBuilder(new Pizza(pizza.base, newToppings));
}
```

Please note this isn't thread save.

Java doesn't have 'real' immutable sets (where adding or removing elements returns a new set, similar to the String methods in Java), but [Scala has](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Set.html).

Comment: Yes I could do that but as I may be adding a number of toppings this seems inefficient.  I'd like to defer the set creation until the `build()`  method is called, if that makes sense?

Comment: If it needs to be fast, you might want to use `EnumSet`

Comment: I know about Scala. ;)  I just was hoping to see a little Java magic.

Comment: I have updated my solution to use `EnumSet`. This should be actually fairly efficient, as it's using a `BitSet` internally. Of course, you could make it more efficient if needed (using a simple `int` bit set) but there is little difference I believe. Anyway you are creating quite many new objects, performance is probably dominated by this.